# How to create .sln file using command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a few `.vcxproj` files. One is `Main.vcxproj` which depends on other `.vcxproj` files. All are `c++` projects.

What I want is to create a `.sln` file with those project files. Is there a way to achieve this using command line?

I am trying to create a batch file which will build the generated `.sln` file. I am able to build the solution if I have the `.sln` file using `msbuild`. But I don't know how to create a `.sln` file using any command utility.

Any hint would be really helpful.

Comment: Why not use something like CMake or Premake5?

Comment: @D-RAJ The batch file I am trying to create is for an organization and there are some restrictions. I can't use `CMake` to build the projects.

Comment: A quick web search turned up this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VagifAbilov.SolutionMaker

Comment: Here is another: https://github.com/microsoft/SlnGen

Comment: @paddy : thank you. But it seems like a GUI tool. I well the github repo of this.

Comment: I skim-read the first link, and it says it can be run from the command line.

Comment: @paddy: There is everything on internet. Even stackOverflow is there. I think the first purpose of SO was to get a quick reference for your doubts. Can you point me to a SO question which don't have an answer on internet. I spent a whole day with `msbuild` for trying to generate a `.sln` file. After that only I logged this question. Again I really appreciate that you helped.

Comment: MSBuild doesn't create solution files.  That's why other tools exist.  Many tools built for cross-platform development have the ability to do this too.  CMake is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @paddy points out in the comments, this is a viable option.

https://github.com/microsoft/SlnGen

It's a command line tool.

Install via:

> dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlnGen.Tool

Navigate the root under which all projects you want to add to your solution, then run:

> slngen

It'll search for `*.*proj` files and add them to a `.sln` file in the current directory.

More options and documentation at https://microsoft.github.io/slngen/.